# How would we sync HttpSession with SessionRegistry in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

**How would we sync HttpSession with SessionRegistry in Spring**

I have the following code which works fine

```
    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentSessionFilter concurrentSessionFilter() {
        return new ConcurrentSessionFilter(sessionRegistry(), new SimpleRedirectSessionInformationExpiredStrategy("/"));
    }
    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
```

```
//Autowired Session Registry

List<String> users = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().stream()
                .filter(u -> !sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(u, false).isEmpty())
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        boolean expieredAtLeastOneSession = false;
        users.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println(sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals());
                        for (final Object user  : sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
                            User actualUser = (User) user;
                            System.out.println("Testing 1");
                            List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(user, true);
                            for(SessionInformation session : sessions) {
                                System.out.println("Testing 2");
                                session.expireNow();
                                sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(session.getSessionId());
                                publisher.publishEvent(AskToExpireSessionEvent.of(session.getSessionId()));
                                expieredAtLeastOneSession = true;
                            }
                        }
```

My scenario is , User A logs in  and user B logs in, A calls this method to invalidate/expire B's session Registry. Uptil here it works fine. However when B refreshes the page he/she is still logged in! This is my question, how can I prevent B from seeing the restricted page or I may also put it, how can the HttpSession be in sync with SessionRegistry?

Answer (score 0):

These settings worked

```
@Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentSessionFilter concurrentSessionFilter() {
        return new ConcurrentSessionFilter(sessionRegistry(), new SimpleRedirectSessionInformationExpiredStrategy("/"));
    }
    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy() {

        ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy =
                new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
        concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(true);
        concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.setMaximumSessions(1);
        return concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFixationProtectionStrategy sessionFixationProtectionStrategy() {
        return new SessionFixationProtectionStrategy();
    }
    @Bean
    public RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    public CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        List<SessionAuthenticationStrategy> sessionAuthenticationStrategyList = new ArrayList<>();
        sessionAuthenticationStrategyList.add(concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy());
        sessionAuthenticationStrategyList.add(sessionFixationProtectionStrategy());
        sessionAuthenticationStrategyList.add(registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy());

        return new CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategyList);
    }
```

and

```
http....and().sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).expiredUrl("/logout")
                .and().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy());
```

Now It is logging out users on refresh. I think I should setup an (periodic) Ajax call to the server to see if the user is logged in and redirect if not.